# face recognition android app

Tags: android

I need to develop an android app that performs:

1.face detection(I have done this following http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/face-detection-example-tutorials-in-android/)

2.I need to recognize the the faces detected in step 1

I have gone through links for opencv for android(http://opencv.org/android) but I am not clear 
where to start with face recognition...any help..Thanx in advance.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I strongly advice you to use the `FaceDetector.Face` Class included in Android from API 1.
It is by far the simplest thing you can do if you need only to detect the face (the class gives you eyes position, midpoint of eyes and pose of the face) see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html)

If you want to go with OpenCV it is a more complicated, and I do not see the point in doing this since you only need face detection. If you like I can give you some guidance on OpenCV as well.

EDIT EDIT EDIT

If you need face recognition you will NEED to use OpenCV. Good luck with your work!
You will need to train a classifier with the picture of the face to recognize and then run the classifier on the faces you want to recognize. It is not an easy task but is doable, I advise you to get a book on OpenCV and understand how the objectdetection features work.

Comment: thanq for the answer...I have detected the faces using FaceDetector.Face as I mentioned in the link above....but I am stuck with how to recogise faces using opencv for android

Comment: @Sindhu Guptha see my edits

Comment: @Sindhu Guptha Thank you. Please let me know how your work progress. But you really need to read a book on OpenCV because real face recognition is not an easy thing, you need to grab the theory (which I actually do not currently)

Comment: can u provide me any links for going through??????

Comment: @Sindhu Guptha here is the offical documentation of OpernCV http://opencv.org/ but you need to understand the theory, so I can recommend books like these http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=opencv